# Spring session redis SSL support using spring boot 1.4.7

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

We are looking for a way to enable SSL/TLS support for session management using Spring Boot 1.4.7 and the corresponding spring-session-data-redis starter package? Upgrading to Spring boot 1.5.0, which seems to add the property `spring.redis.ssl`, is not desired as there are many dependency issues. Using a non-encrypted redis server is also not an option.

Are there any other properties or alternatives?

The have tried the following:

- We are attempting to upgrade to spring 1.5.0 but have many dependency issues that are complicating the upgrade.
- Researched lettuce.io properties to see if we can set the pool properties from there.
- Identified that support for SSL was added in Spring boot 1.5.0.

Our project is setup like this:

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

...

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  redis:
    #ssl: true # only supported in 1.5.0 and above
    host: redis.hostname.com
    port: 6379
    password: "##########"
  session:
    store-type: redis 
    redis:
      flush-mode: on_save
      namespace: appname
```

At startup we get the following error message:

```
2019-05-31 13:58:11.223 ERROR 2104 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at com.tangocard.web.admintools.Application.main(Application.java:28) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:198) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:345) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:223) ~[spring-session-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:99) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:12) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:191) ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:80) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1677) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:87) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202-ea]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_202-ea]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_202-ea]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_202-ea]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_202-ea]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_202-ea]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158) ~[jedis-2.8.2.jar:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?